# Python type annotations breaking syntax highlighting in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to add type annotations (for return types) to my functions then the syntax highlighting in vscode is not working after that point. Do you have a hint on what setting to change to fix the issues?

VSCode Version 1.67.1
Python Version 3.10.8

#### Code with type annotations

```py
def median_absolute_deviaton(data: list) -> float:
    """Returns the median absolute deivation (MAD) [float]."""
    med = median(data)
    deviations = [abs(i-med) for i in data]
    return statistics.median(deviations)
```

#### Image with working syntax highlighting

[image: Working syntax highlighting]

#### Image with broken syntax highlighting

[image: Broken syntax highlighting]

Comment: This is clearly a bug in VSCode or the plugin you are using and you should check the relevant issue trackers. If you want to post your issue there, make sure to include your code as _text_, not just the screenshots. Also, what does this have to do with `mypy`?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). This can help others attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED: It was caused by the "Python for VSCode" extension. Uninstalling helped. Found it here: https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/issues/138#issuecomment-403538358

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install and/or select the right Python interpreter:

[image: VSCode Interpreter Selection]

There's a python version shown at the lower right corner of the VSCode window. Click it, then select a version of python at least as high as python 3.5 (the version of python where type annotations were added).

If you don't have a version of python that high listed, then you'll need to install one.

If you have one installed and it isn't listed, then you can manually enter the path to the version you installed.

Comment: Before I used 3.10.8 and now 3.11.1 - both don't work.